# Function to detect Columns getting Updated For Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I wrote a function to detect which columns are getting updated for a table.

This Table is present in Oracle Apex.

I use this function to send mail for Update performed **through APEX UI** on it.

Trigger Code:

```
    create or replace TRIGGER TRIAL AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
  result varchar2(4000);
begin
result := snap_fun('TABLE_NAME');


   SEND_MAIL('JOHN@****',
    'TABLE Modified',result,'bidev-noreply@***','HOST');   
 end;
```

Function Code

```
create or replace function SNAP_FUN(inTableName in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  result varchar2(4000);
  sep    varchar2(2) := null;
begin
  for c in (select column_name from all_tab_columns where  table_name = inTableName) loop
    if updating(c.column_name) then
      result := result || sep || c.column_name;
      sep    := ', ';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return result;
end;
```

Problem : When i am updating any column through back end, i am receiving correct mail with only columns that are **actually** being updated but when i Update through Oracle Apex (using UI), I receive the list of all the columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what your APEX application is doing.  But my wager is that you want to check whether the `:new.column` equals the `:old.column` value rather than whether the `update` statement includes the column in question.  In general, applications are going to be written to put all the columns they could update in the `update` statement rather than dynamically building an `update` statement depending on which columns were actually updated.

Comment: And that's what Apex is doing, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
So this is the Implementation i came up with: 


> I  have 15 columns to address  so:


1. Check if difference exists.
2.Yes Proceed to check next flag
3.Insert Each Change with column name.
3.After checking all move them to Single Variable by looping through Log Table
4.Push this to SMTP Proc.
5.Truncate table(used Autonomous Trans along with Delete proc.)






  




CREATE TABLE "DW"."LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT" 
           (    "CHANGED_COLUMN" VARCHAR2(255)  ,
            "CHANGED" VARCHAR2(2)  ,
            "MONTH_ID" VARCHAR2(255)  ,
            "CHANGED_BY" VARCHAR2(255) 
           );
   
/

    
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DW.PROC_TRUNCATE_TABLE (TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || TABLE_NAME;
    END;
    
    /
    
    
    
    create or replace TRIGGER "DW"."TRG_W_SUPPL_SNAPSHOT_CONTROL_G"  
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON DW.W_SUPPL_SNAPSHOT_CONTROL_G
    REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
        BODY VARCHAR2(4000);
        ENV        VARCHAR2(255);
        I_EMAIL_TO VARCHAR2(4000);
        CHANGE_BY VARCHAR2(255);
    BEGIN
    BEGIN
    BEGIN
        Select SUCCESS_NOTIFY_LIST into I_EMAIL_TO from DW.W_ETL_EMAIL_CONTROL where TASK_NAME='W_SUPPL_SNAPSHOT_CONTROL_G';
        SELECT VALUE into ENV FROM DW.W_ETL_EMAIL_CONFIG WHERE NAME='EMAIL_FROM';
    
       IF INSERTING THEN
          SELECT SYSDATE, NVL(v('APP_USER'),'AUTO_INSERT'), NVL(v('APP_USER'),'AUTO_INSERT'), SYSDATE
          INTO :NEW.CREATED_ON_DT, :NEW.CREATED_BY,:NEW.CHANGED_BY, :NEW.CHANGED_ON_DT
                FROM DUAL;
          SELECT :NEW.CHANGED_BY INTO CHANGE_BY FROM DUAL;
       END IF;
        IF UPDATING THEN
          SELECT SYSDATE, v('APP_USER')
          INTO :NEW.CHANGED_ON_DT, :NEW.CHANGED_BY
                FROM DUAL;
        SELECT :NEW.CHANGED_BY INTO CHANGE_BY FROM DUAL;
       END IF;
    END;
     IF UPDATING('DFT_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.DFT_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.DFT_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'DFT_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.DFT_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF  UPDATING('WESTIN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND( :NEW.WESTIN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.WESTIN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'WESTIN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.WESTIN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('ASCENTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.ASCENTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.ASCENTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'ASCENTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.ASCENTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('TELX_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND( :NEW.TELX_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.TELX_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'TELX_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.TELX_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('DIGITAL_REALTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.DIGITAL_REALTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.DIGITAL_REALTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'DIGITAL_REALTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.DIGITAL_REALTY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('TELECITY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND( :NEW.TELECITY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.TELECITY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'TELECITY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.TELECITY_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('INXN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.INXN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.INXN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'INXN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.INXN_LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('INXN_OA_LOCK_FLG') AND( :NEW.INXN_OA_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.INXN_OA_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'INXN_OA_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.INXN_OA_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('TERACO_OA_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.TERACO_OA_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.TERACO_OA_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'TERACO_OA_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.TERACO_OA_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('TERACO_LA_LOCK_FLG') AND( :NEW.TERACO_LA_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.TERACO_LA_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'TERACO_LA_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.TERACO_LA_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                  NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.LEASE_ACT_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('CUST_LOCK_FLG') AND( :NEW.CUST_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.CUST_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'CUST_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.CUST_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('PROPERTY_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.PROPERTY_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.PROPERTY_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'PROPERTY_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.PROPERTY_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('OA_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.OA_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.OA_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'OA_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.OA_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
            IF UPDATING('FUSION_OA_LOCK_FLG') AND ( :NEW.FUSION_OA_LOCK_FLG <> :OLD.FUSION_OA_LOCK_FLG ) THEN
                INSERT INTO DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT (
                    CHANGED_COLUMN,
                    CHANGED,
                    MONTH_ID,
                    CHANGED_BY
                ) VALUES (
                    'FUSION_OA_LOCK_FLG',
                    :NEW.FUSION_OA_LOCK_FLG,
                    :NEW.MONTH_ID,
                    NVL( V('APP_USER'),' MANUAL UPDATE')
                );
    
            END IF;
    
    END;
        FOR I IN (
            SELECT
                CHANGED_COLUMN,
                CHANGED,
                MONTH_ID,
              CHANGED_BY
            FROM
                DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT
        ) LOOP
            BODY := BODY
                 || ( 'Modification Performed : '||chr(13)||chr(10)
                      || 'Flag :                 '|| I.CHANGED_COLUMN||chr(13)||chr(10)
                      || 'Period :            '|| I.MONTH_ID||chr(13)||chr(10)
                      || 'TO:                     ' || I.CHANGED||chr(13)||chr(10)
                      || ' BY :                  '|| I.CHANGED_BY||chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10) );
        END LOOP;
        SELECT SUCCESS_NOTIFY_LIST INTO I_EMAIL_TO FROM DW.W_ETL_EMAIL_CONTROL WHERE TASK_NAME = 'W_SUPPL_SNAPSHOT_CONTROL_G';
        SELECT  VALUE INTO ENV FROM DW.W_ETL_EMAIL_CONFIG WHERE NAME = 'EMAIL_FROM';
    
        SEND_MAIL(I_EMAIL_TO, 'SUPPLEMENTAL SNAPSHOT CONTROL TABLE MODIFIED', BODY,ENV, 'host'
        );
        PROC_TRUNCATE_TABLE('DW.LOG_SUPPLEMENTAL_SNAPSHOT');
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a workaround like this due to the behavior of Apex UI. You will need to test every column as Justin Cave noted in his comment. The column list can be removed from the **AFTER UPDATE** clause if updates only occur via the Apex UI. Finally, if multiple rows can be updated in one transaction, you could use a compound trigger and gather all of the row-level changes in one email.

[Oracle Create Trigger Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html)

[Oracle Data Type Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-1563C817-86BF-430B-99AB-322EE2E29187)

```
CREATE TRIGGER sample_trg
-- can list each column explicitly if updates can occur outside of Apex UI
-- I only put two in this example
AFTER UPDATE OF number_col, date_col ON sample_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

  l_result VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_sep    VARCHAR2(2) := ', ';

BEGIN

  -- check for differences on each of your columns
  -- I only put two in this example
  IF (:old.number_col IS NULL AND :new.number_col IS NOT NULL
      OR :old.number_col IS NOT NULL AND :new.number_col IS NULL
      OR :old.number_col != :new.number_col)
  THEN
    l_result := l_result || 'NUMBER_COL' || l_sep;
  END IF;

  IF (:old.date_col IS NULL AND :new.date_col IS NOT NULL
      OR :old.date_col IS NOT NULL AND :new.date_col IS NULL
      OR :old.date_col != :new.date_col )
  THEN
    l_result := l_result || 'DATE_COL';
  END IF;

  -- remove any trailing separator
  l_result := RTRIM(l_result, l_sep);

  -- if there were any changed columns send email
  IF (LENGTH(l_result) > 0) THEN
    send_mail('john@****', 'SAMPLE_TBL is modified ' || l_result
              ,'bi-dev@*****', 'HOST');
  END IF;

END sample_trg;
```

Comment: Hi Jason , don't need compound trigger Can be done from Single Row level.